# Strapi does not run on Mac M1

Tags: macos, strapi, apple-m1

I am trying to run Strapi admin panel on my Mac M1. I have setup the Rosetta terminal for the same.
After running `yarn develop`, I am getting the following error.

```
Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module

Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-darwin-x64.node'
```

[image]
**There are multiple solutions on the web, but which one would be the correct. My Nodejs Version in 16.14.0**

Comment: try this one: `npm install sharp --unsafe-perm`

Comment: @n00b didn't work

Answer (score 0):

im currently working with the same node version, in fact im working with docker compose and mac m1, and i did have similar problems with dependencies, for me the solution was use yarn for install dependencies.

Just verify if you have yarn with the command "yarn -v" if you dont have run the command "npm install --global yarn" then in the directory with the proyect, run "yarn install"